# Modify generated column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

I have created a database table in Oracle with an auto generated column:

```
ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1)
```

Now I do not need it to be generated automatically. I tried to write:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY id number;
```

But it did not work. The database gives an error:

```
32795.0000 -  "cannot insert into a generated always identity column"
```

Can someone please explain how to solve this issue without dropping the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(There's no such thing as "PLSQL database"; PL/SQL is a procedural extension to Oracle's SQL. Database is **Oracle**.)

---

Drop the identity:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id number generated always as identity (start with 1 increment by 1));

Table created.

SQL> alter table test modify id drop identity;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, it works, how can I return identity after dropping it?

Comment: You can't, as far as I can tell. You'd have to add a brand new identity column to the table.